# Php loop through array with key value pair and save to database

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array $s which stores incoming data from a JSON feed. The format of the array is like this:

```
     $s = array("tweets"=>1, "likes"=>4, "plusones"=>7);
```

How would I loop through the array: **$s**, and pick the values of the keys so that I can then assign to the variables $tweets, $likes and $plusones.

This was what I did but I'm not able to extract the values and store them in the variables I've set to nil

```
   foreach($social_shares as $social_share=>$include){
     echo $social_share . ": " . $include . "<br>";
        $tweets = nil;
        $likes = nil;
        $plusones = nil;

   $sql4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO social_shares(article_id, tweets, likes, plusones ) VALUES ($s -> article_id ,'$tweets', '$likes', '$plusones')");
    }
```

Comment: The question is sloppy and hard to read. If you want attention, give some effort.

Comment: You are probably looking for `list(...) = each(...)` statement.

Comment: There's something called [extract()](http://es1.php.net/extract), but you should only used with data you trust (you created it), not with data fetched from outside.

Comment: @barell I just got into php programming so could you please give an example of how to use the functions you have listed?

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia The data is from a JSON feed so I guess that function would not suffice. I have however noted it down

Comment: Looping through an array is something extremely basic - a simple Google search will give numerous examples

Comment: And, is there any reason you've added the `multidimensional array` tag? The example you've given is only 1D

Comment: I changed the tags since they seemed too wrong. No SQL nor multidimensional tags here, but instead JSON. Please feel free to revert.

Comment: @ChrisW Please check my last edit to see how I had looped through the array. The multidimensional array was a noobie mistake since I'm a ruby on rails developer and we call that kind of array a hash

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia. I've just added the sql but thanks for the heads up

Comment: *PLEASE* don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code - they are now deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now we're talking. The first question didn't show any effort from your part. However, I need to tell you that this is [PHP arrays 101](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). You can simply do:

```
$tweets = $social_shares['tweets'];
$likes = $social_shares['likes'];
$plusones = $social_shares['plusones'];
```

However, you cannot use SQL like that. You are vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Please read over this thread to see possible solutions:

> [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/938236)

Comment: It worked. Reading through the SQL INJECTION and I have to say this is very new but exremely insightful especially the answer part where he/she used PDO